# update form redirecting to root_url on submit - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**Updated w/ dev log. See below**

I'm using vanity urls in my routing and I"m assuming it has something to do with it... 
In short my issue is I'm unable to have the user update their information. I can get the edit form to show up but on submit the update method doesn't run and I neither get a "fail" or "success".

The relevant routes look like this:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :friends
  end

 match '/:username/edit' => 'users#edit', :as => "edit_user"
 match '/:username' => 'users#show', :as => "user"
```

My form looks like this now, but I've tried a couple different things.

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => user_path(@user.username) do |form| %>  
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => form.object %>
 <div class="form">  
    <p> <%= form.label :description, "Message to friends" %>  <br />  
     <%= form.text_area :description %> </p> 

     <%= form.submit "Update" %>  
 </div>  
 <% end %>
```

The edit and update controllers look like this:

```
 def edit 
    @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username]) 
  end

def update 
    @user = User.find(params[:id]) 
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) 
       redirect_to user_url(current_user.username), :flash => { :success => "wham" }
    else
      redirect_to user_url(current_user.username), :error => { :error => "shiz" }
    end
end
```

Currently, when the update form is submitting, you get directed to the users url but nothing happens. I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

**Update ----**
I have changed my routes as described below using to_param. This works just fine but the problem still persists where my update form just redirects to the root_url. Under rake routes I get the correct path for update and the edit form is displaying correctly. Here is what I get form rake routes:

```
PUT    /users/:id(.:format)   {:controller=>"users", :action=>"update"}
```

And this is the dev log from submitting my form

```
Started POST "/1" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Jan 05 16:09:54 -0500 2011
  Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update User", "authenticity_token"=>"OM1lIzizuFCYlxC3XmtmG/btqAsyjekHtqsiwlUDn3M=", "utf8"=>"✓", "username"=>"1", "user"=>{"description"=>"Update the message please"}}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = '1') LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/
ApplicationController::current_user
ApplicationController::current_user_session
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
ApplicationController::current_user_session
Completed 302 Found in 44ms


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed Jan 05 16:09:54 -0500 2011
  Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
ApplicationController::current_user
ApplicationController::current_user_session
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
ApplicationController::current_user_session
ApplicationController::current_user
ApplicationController::current_user
ApplicationController::current_user
ApplicationController::current_user
Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (22.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 61ms (Views: 32.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Why does that redirect happen??

Comment: Check your development.log file. Does it gives any hint about what is happening?

Comment: form some reason I'm getting a redirect after the update... my dev log looks this:Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update", "authenticity_token"=>"OM1lIzizuFCYlxC3XmtmG/btqAsyjekHtqsiwlUDn3M=", "utf8"=>"✓", "username"=>"1", "user"=>{"description"=>"This should update" }}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."username" = '1') LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/
ApplicationController::current_user
ApplicationController::current_user_session

Answer (score 2):

Rather than defining custom routes for this, just define the `to_param` method on the `User` class:

```
def to_param
  username.parameterize
end
```

Then for your routes, the `params[:id]` value will be the username's paramertized version. For instance, mine would be `ryan-bigg`.

Comment: ..and once you have that, you need to alter your finders to ensure you can search your model based on this parameterized string.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I didn't know about the to_param method and I was able to launch out the edit form as you described without defining the url in the form. I'm however still having trouble getting the update form to work after submit... I looked at my development log and it appears that there is a redirect to root after I submit the form. Any ideas why that might happen. Thanks

Comment: @owilde1900: I have no idea without any further information to go on, sorry.

Comment: I ended up receiving some info that to_param has to be defined in ActiveRecord. Not sure why this wasn't already defined already but what ended up fixing it adding :url => { :action => "update" } to the form.

Comment: @owilde1900: If the update form wasn't working perhaps the to_param value was non-parameterized and contained invalid route characters.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your log doesn't indicate this is the case, I'd also check if the   `attr_accessible` has `:description` added to it in User model. It's happened to me before - the form seems to work but information doesn't get stored.